# Finding maximum of this function in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

This particular question is from my assignment in complex analysis and I need to verify my answer and way of solving.

> Let $f$ be analytic for $|z| \leq 3$ such that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z| \leq 3$ and has $n$ roots at $w_{k}=e^{2 k \pi i / 3}(k=0,1,2, \ldots, n-1),$ the $n$ th roots of unity. What is the maximum value of $|f(0)| ?$ Which functions attain a maximum?

Attempt: Instead of using maximum modulus principle, I wrote the function as f(z) = $(z-w_1)... (z-w_k) $ and then putting z=0. $ |f(0)|= e^{ \frac{2k(2k-1) πi} {3}} $ . But here maximum will depend upon value of k. So, how to find maximum?

Also, I don't understand what it means by which functions attain it's maximum.

If there is another method by which it can be solved more elegantly, please tell it.

Comment: What you wrote can't be correct because the modulus of $f(0)$  cannot be a complex number.

Comment: $f$ is analytic. Perhaps we can use this to impose some conditions on its form and its derivatives (which might help us find the maximum value at origin).

Comment: hint: use $w=z/3$ to reduce to a function on the unit disc and then take out the roots with a Blaschke product and conclude that $|f(0)| \le (1/3)^n$ - the image has a weird statement as on one hand it describes the roots as the $n$ th roots of unity, on the other it has them as third roots of unity, but the solution is correct either way ($n=3$ in the latter case, or even general $n$ if you take third roots of unity but allow multiplicity)

Comment: @Conrad Blaskhe product was not taught in lectures. So, Is there a way to attempt the question without using it? And Do you mind writing a detailed answer if you got time? It would really help me.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $g(z)=f(3z), |z| \le 1$ we get a holomorphic function that sends the unit disc to itself and has $n$ zeroes at $z_{k}=e^{2 k \pi i / 3}/3$, where $k=0,1,2, \ldots, n-1$ and $f(0)=g(0)$ so we can use $g$

If there were no zeroes then, of course, $|g(0)| \le 1$ with equality if it is a unit modulus constant, so we need to find which analytic functions preserve the unit disc (including being $1$ in absolute value on the boundary) and have zeroes only at the specified (finitely many) points inside (also under some simple conditions one can actually extend to infinitely many zeroes inside).

But for one zero $|z_0|<1$ we can take the standard automorphism $\phi_{z_0}(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{1-\bar z_0z}$ for which of course $|\phi_{z_0}(0)|=|z_0|, |\phi_{z_0}(e^{it}))|=1$.

This clearly means that the product of such automorphisms (also called a finite Blaschke product), $B(z)=\phi_{z_0}(z)\phi_{z_1}(z)..\phi_{z_{n-1}}(z)$ satisfies that $B$ has zeroes only at the given $n$ points, $B$ preserves the unit disc and $|B|=1$ on the unit circle; hence $g/B$ is a holomorphic function from the unit disc to itself (continuous on the boundary) so by maximum modulus $|g/B| \le 1$ and since $g/B$ has no zeroes, we can actually attain maximum precisely when $g=\alpha B$ for some arbitrary $|\alpha|=1$,
hence $|g(0)| \le |B(0)|$ with equality possible.

Particularizing to our case and the given $z_k$ leads to $|f(0)|=|g(0)| \le |B(0)|=\frac{1}{3^n}$ with equality precisely when $f(z)=\alpha B(z/3), |\alpha|=1, |z| \le 3$