# maximum of analytic function at certain point

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

The question comes from the answer to this question [Finding maximum of this function in complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888601/finding-maximum-of-this-function-in-complex-analysis)

The answer claims that "hence $g/B$ is a holomorphic function from the unit disc to itself".

We only know that $g: D \to D$ and $B: D \to D$ and $g/B$ is holomorphic with removable singularities, right? Why does that guarantee $g/B: D \to D$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\frac  g B| \leq1$ in $|z|=1$. By Maximum Modulus Principle the inequality holds for $|z| <1$ also. By Open Mapping Theorem for analytic functions the image of the open unit disk under $\frac g B$ is an open set so this image must be contained in $D$.

Comment: One quick question. If $g/B$ does not have zeros, doesn't that imply (by applying mmp on $B/g$) $|g/B|$ is a constant?

Comment: We only know that $|f(3z)| \leq 1$ for $|z|=1$. Se we do not know know that $|\frac B g| \leq 1$ for $|z|=1$. So MMP for $\frac B g $ does not yield any conclusion.  @SmoothKen

Comment: I see. Thank you.